# How to backport a patch to my current kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I used to download `compat-wireless-3.6.8-1` on Ubuntu 12.04
And successfully compile it into target files for `compat.ko`,
`cfg80211.ko`, `mac80211.ko`, `ath.ko`, `ath9k_hw.ko`, `ath9k_common.ko`
`ath9k.ko` .

Now I need to use linux kernel 3.11 above version.

So I download
the new version with `backports-3.13-rc2-1`  and use it in the Ubuntu 13.10 .
But I found that I don't have `.config` file to compile it.

So, I copy the `.config` file
from source `compat-wireless-3.6.8-1`. And use the `.config` to compile the source
code of `backports-3.13-rc2-1` .

And the results was , there is only `compat.ko`.

My question is that how can I get all the device driver ( for compat.ko,
`cfg80211.ko`, `mac80211.ko`, `ath.ko`, `ath9k_hw.ko`, `ath9k_common.ko`
`ath9k.ko` .) and how to compile it use the souce code from `backports-3.13-rc2-1`.

Or where can I find  the Makefile or `.config` file for `backports-3.13-rc2-1`?

Comment: "backports" of what? The kernel?

Comment: @Braiam--backports of most wireless and some ethernet drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the extracted file is on your desktop, in a terminal, do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13-rc2-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r ath9k && sudo modprobe ath9k
```

'sudo make install' will produce a signing key warning that you may safely ignore.